# Hover event propagated across multiple TableViews

Tags: javafx

I would like to know if it is possible to highlight multiple tables' rows upon hovering over a row in a table.

There doesn't seem to be a hover-index from the hover property of the TableView. The hoverProperty only  indicates if it is being hovered.

Also, how do I force hover state of a row in a table?

Here's an example when the user hover over a row in TableView 1, TableView 2's respective row will highlight too.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| TableView 1                        |  TableView 2                          |  
|                                    |                                       |
|==Entry A===========================|==Entry 1==============================| <-- highlighted row
|  Entry B                           |  Entry 2                              |     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thank you!

EDIT: I'm using JDK 1.8

EDIT 2:
Thanks to James_D for the tip I've managed to come up with a solution. Not too sure if it is the best way to implement but it works.

```
public class CustomTableView<T> extends TableView<T> {
    private static final String HIGHLIGHT = "highlight";
    private final IntegerProperty currHoverIdx = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

    public CustomTableView() {
        super();
        registerCallback();

        currHoverIdx.set(-1);
    }

    public IntegerProperty highlightProperty() {
        return currHoverIdx;
    }

    private void registerCallback() {
        final Callback<TableView<T>, TableRow<T>> rowFac = this.getRowFactory();
        final PseudoClass highlightPc = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass(HIGHLIGHT);

        final Callback<TableView<T>, TableRow<T>> modRowFac = param -> {
            TableRow<T> row;
            if (rowFac != null) {
                row = rowFac.call(param);
            } else {
                row = new TableRow<T>();
            }

            row.hoverProperty().addListener((ov, oldVal, newVal) -> {
                if (newVal) {
                    currHoverIdx.set(row.getIndex());
                } else {
                    currHoverIdx.set(-1);
                }
            });

            currHoverIdx.addListener((ov, oldVal, newVal) -> {
                Number valOld = (Number) oldVal;
                int rowIdx = row.getIndex();
                if (valOld.intValue() == rowIdx) {
                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(highlightPc, false);
                } else {
                    Number valNew = (Number) newVal;
                    if (valNew.intValue() == rowIdx) {
                        row.pseudoClassStateChanged(highlightPc, true);
                    }
                }
            });

            return row;
        };
        this.setRowFactory(modRowFac);
    }
}
```

How to use it:

```
CustomTableView<Integer> left;
CustomTableView<String> right;

...
...
...

IntegerProperty left = leftTable.highlightProperty();
IntegerProperty right = leftTable.highlightProperty();

left.addListener((ov, oldVal, newVal) -> {
    Number valNew = (Number) newVal;
    right.set(valNew.intValue());
});

right.addListener((ov, oldVal, newVal) -> {
    Number valNew = (Number) newVal;
    left.set(valNew.intValue());
});
```

CSS:

```
.table-view .table-row-cell:highlight {
    -fx-background-color: #D3D3D3;
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: transparent;
}
```

EDIT 3:
If there are scrolling artifacts (The row highlighting not in sync), add the following lines to the scroll events:

```
left.refresh();
right.refresh();
```

P.S. -- I tried to omit parts of my code unrelated to this question, but the gist of it is there.

Comment: It seems like the more difficult problem with this setup would be synchronizing the scroll positions of the two tables (without which synchronizing the hover state would be weird for the user). Are you sure these should be two tables, and not just a single table with more columns?

Comment: I managed to synchronise the scrolling between both tables. The issue is that the table I needed to make had fixed columns (left) and scrollable columns (right). Or is there a better way of implementing fixed and scrollable columns? Thanks!

Comment: There's no way that I know of to freeze some columns and have others scrollable. The approach I'd use, I think, is to create an `IntegerProperty` holding the currently-hovered row. Use a `rowFactory` on each table to create `TableRow` instances that update that property with their index when they're hovered, and observe that property to compare their index. Probably you should use a custom CSS `Pseudoclass` to represent your custom hovered state, and define the CSS in terms of that pseudoclass to style the hovered rows.

Comment: afair, controlsfx has a tableView with fixed columns